# Down-voting and no comments

Tags: support, feature-request, status-declined, down-votes, comments

In these sites, down-voting has become a passion to prove *intelligence*. Yesterday, I got two upvoted answers **downvoted simultaneously** (Someone has down-voted both within 1 min). I think they're too busy in leaving comments and reading [Etiquette](https://physics.stackexchange.com/faq#etiquette)

Why isn't there a rule: "For Downvoting upvoted posts, comments are must"

The posted users don't know "For which silly reason, they've been downvoted..."
Then, how would we correct the answers? Only one choice left out: "Answers must be deleted".

Comment: Related: https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1372/2451 and links therein.

Comment: Good idea on the main site, but not on meta. **Edit:** But that may discourage downvotes. That's not a good idea.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reasons you're not required to leave a comment when downvoting, and why that is not going to change, are explained in detail in many questions on Meta Stack Overflow ([example](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/encouraging-people-to-explain-down-votes)).

When you downvote a post, you're *encouraged* (but never required) to explain what can be improved about it. Of course, this is also encouraged even if you don't downvote the post.

Coming at it from the other direction, when your post is downvoted and/or someone suggests an improvement, you have no obligation to do anything about it. Correcting the answer or deleting it are not your only choices. You can just leave it alone.

Comment: There's also another view which is popular in these sites... When someone downvotes, all of them concentrate their brains into - to downvote the same post **again and again**

Comment: Drop the persecution complex and try improving your questions.

Comment: @zephyr: Oh, I see... so you're saying to think **POSITIVE**... I'll try..!

Comment: Sure. You are not required to do many things in life but we do them anyway. Why be polite, why help others if it does not benefit you...

Answer (score -1):

Downvoting without a reason is plain stupid. I **will** upvote every single downvoted question that has no justification. For example, check this question-->http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/35928/a-different-lasing-medium/35936#35936

So, the OP has a few misconceptions about Laser systems, so what? I tried to interpret the question as best as I could, but of course the motherfunkers who probably downvoted the OP downvoted me as well. Hazard of the internet I guess. You need to sort this out bro...

Comment: have you even read any of the many linked reasons for this? BTW I just down voted you for lack of research effort :)

Comment: And did you notice that that question has been completely revised since those votes were cast (not that it's been improved much).

Comment: @zephyr, and how exactly did you contribute to either improving the question or providing a reasonable interpretation? Just sayin' man...just because you don't understand the question doesn't make it crap.

Comment: @AntillarMaximus believe me I am quite capable of understanding the "question". You don't seem to realize that voting as a means of quality control is just as important as asking or answering questions.

Comment: This guy seems to be spamming the board with a ton of ridiculous crap, I guess just to start conversations? If we want to maintain a decent level of quality here, it is important that lousy questions be down voted and good ones up voted. The point of voting is not to give people warm fuzzies, it's to sort content by quality.

Comment: @AntillarMaximus oh and I see that the question has now been closed as "Not a real question". So do you still think it ought to be upvoted?